# Facebook access token issue in JS implementation

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth-2.0

I am new to FB apps and trying to get the accessToken for my website using JS. I have followed the steps given on the API docs, but I keep getting an

"error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "Error validating application."
   }

I know that theres some issue with my implementation. Can someone please help me out.

If you can provide a link to a tutorial/code snippet that would be really great.

Comment: can you show what you have so far? did you register an app properly with all correct URLs?

Comment: Yes I have registered the app, got the app id and also have my site URL.

Answer (score 0):

Since today there is a change in Facebook Graph API, the given access token is now URI-encoded, it may be this your problem, give a look here: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=273730